# How to package a Python module

Tags: python, module, packaging

I am a newbie to Python and I have been going through the exercises in LPTHW:
http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex46.html

The explanation of packaging the author gave was very vague, so I did some researching, but I was still left with some questions in the end.

Firstly, what happens if you have a module that imports another module? Do you put the module that is imported into a subdirectory of the directory containing the first module, or in another separate directory in the root?

Secondly, once you have installed the entire package how do you run any scripts that are in the bin folder?

Comment: Some examples https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Firstly, what happens if you have a module that imports another
>   module? Do you put the module that is imported into a subdirectory of
>   the directory containing the first module, or in another separate
>   directory in the root?

A module is just a file with Python code - you don't need to put it in a separate directory. The easiest option is to put the file in the same directory that contains the module that will be doing the import.

If you put it in some other directory **and that directory is not a package** you will not be able to import it at all (unless you manually mess around with `PYTHONPATH` which you shouldn't).

> Secondly, once you have installed the entire package how do you run
>   any scripts that are in the bin folder?

The way to do this is to specify the scripts for your application in the `setup.py` file using [`console_scripts`](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/distributing.html#console-scripts). This way, when your package is installed, your scripts will be built correctly and placed in the right directories on the target platform so that you can directly execute them (without being aware of their location on the filesystem).

As an example, you can browse the [`setup.py` file for the django project](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/setup.py).

If you are installing a package, you don't need to know where the actual script is located - simply install the package and execute the command directly from your prompt.

Comment: Thanks, i have read the documentation on the setup script and specified my script in the setup.py, but i have not yet tried to install my package. Could you give me an example of how i would run my script once i have installed my package? for example, lets say i have a script that is named stuff.py, what is the exact command i would use to run the script from the command line once my package has been installed?

Comment: you would type `stuff.py`.